# как заменить числа в списке с помощью цикла for

Tags: python

имеется список в котором все числа нужно заменить на `+`
мои попытки:

```
Russia, France = (int(x)for x in input().split())

res_r_result = []

if Russia > France:
    b = Russia - France
    while b > 0:
        res_r_result.append(b)
        b -= 1

print(res_r_result)

for x in res_r_result:
    res_r_result[x] = '+'
print(res_r_result)
```

Comment: #ДамирНабиуллин вам мой ответ помог или нет?

Comment: а в строке только числа или буквы есть ? нужно прям заменить или можно новый список сделать ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
for x in range(len(res_r_result)):
    res_r_result[x] = "+" 
print(res_r_result)
```